# Making a support structure "manifold" in openscad

Tags: openscad

I am trying to build a support structure around a cylinder in openscad, but I cannot seem to make the angled part of the structure "manifold"

```
inner_slide_tube_inner_radius=14.9/2;
leadpipe_wall_thickness=14.9/2;
leadpipe_length=200;
mouthpiece_receiver_large_radius=0.546*25.4/2;

NoSpokes = 4;
SpokesWide = 3; 
SpokesHigh = 3;
SpokesLong = leadpipe_length/2*0.75;
SpokesLong2 = leadpipe_length/2;

//if I comment out this section, then I can render a single support angle part when NoSpokes=1
for (i=[1:NoSpokes]) 
rotate([0,0,360/NoSpokes*i])
translate([mouthpiece_receiver_large_radius+leadpipe_wall_thickness,-SpokesWide/2,0])
cube([SpokesLong, SpokesWide, SpokesHigh]);
//

for (i=[1:NoSpokes]) 
rotate([0,0,360/NoSpokes*i])polyhedron(
points=[
[mouthpiece_receiver_large_radius+SpokesLong+leadpipe_wall_thickness-SpokesHigh, -SpokesWide/2,  SpokesHigh],
[mouthpiece_receiver_large_radius+SpokesLong+leadpipe_wall_thickness-SpokesHigh, SpokesWide/2,  SpokesHigh],
[inner_slide_tube_inner_radius, SpokesWide/2,  SpokesLong2],
[inner_slide_tube_inner_radius, -SpokesWide/2, SpokesLong2],
[mouthpiece_receiver_large_radius+SpokesLong+leadpipe_wall_thickness, -SpokesWide/2,  SpokesHigh],
[mouthpiece_receiver_large_radius+SpokesLong+leadpipe_wall_thickness, SpokesWide/2,  SpokesHigh],
[inner_slide_tube_inner_radius, SpokesWide/2,  SpokesLong2+SpokesHigh],
[inner_slide_tube_inner_radius, -SpokesWide/2, SpokesLong2+SpokesHigh]],
faces=[[1,0,3,2],
[1,5,4,0],
[2,3,7,6],
[1,5,6,2],
[0,4,7,3],
[4,5,6,7]
]);
```

I know that this is really naive question, but I am rather stuck as I keep getting the warning `WARNING: Object may not be a valid 2-manifold and may need repair!`

Any help would be greatly appreciated to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your design is not manifold is that some of your polygon don't have the correct winding order. In OpenSCAD, if you preview your design using F2 (Thrown Together), such wrongly winded polygons will be highlighted in pink.